# Relational database schema for survey app

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, database-design

I'm looking to learn CakePHP and I'm followed through with the tutorials and am beginning to grasp the concepts. However, I have progressed on and I am trying now to design a survey style app to learn a bit more about related tables and associated entities.

I jumped in thinking it would be a fairly straightforward project to further my learning but I think I underestimated the database complexity, therefore I am asking if anyone has any examples of the best way to structure my database.

My ultimate goal is:

- The app will contain customers.
- The app will contain questions.
- A customer can have many surveys.
- A survey can contain many questions.
- A survey can contain many answers (each linked to a question in the
  survey).

I've started with the schema below but I'm not sure if this is the most optimal or appropriate design. Does anyone have any thoughts on the proposed schema? I'd love to hear some feedback or suggestions.

[Proposed database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udbYH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your schema could be slightly simpler. The `questions_surveys` link table seems somewhat redundant unless you plan on re-using the same question across multiple surveys. Other than that, you meet your list of requirements. The link between answers and surveys could be omitted as you could link an answer back to a survey through the question entity however there's no harm in having the `survey_id` field for convenience.

Your next step would be to setup all of your Model relationships in Cake, which would take the shape of:

- Customer **hasMany** Survey
- Survey **belongsTo** Customer
- Survey **hasMany** Question (or hasAndBelongsToMany depending on if re-using questions)
- Question **belongsTo** Survey
- Question **hasOne** Answer
- Answer **belongsTo** Question